# how to prevent user from being able to call the same view controller twice in a row from a slide out settings menu?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following function that identifies the navigation controller that is embedded in a tab bar controller and pushes a profile view controller. This function works, but I want to do some check that prevents it from presenting the profile view controller a second time if this function is called from the slide out menu while the profile view controller is the most recently pushed view controller. Here's the function:

```
private func toProfile() {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
        let tbc = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? TabBarController,
        let nav =  tbc.viewControllers?[tbc.selectedIndex] as? UINavigationController else { return }
    let profileVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileVC")
    nav.pushViewController(profileVC, animated: true)
    delegate?.dismissSettingsVC()
}
```

I tried:

```
if nav.viewControllers.last == profileVC {
    print("Do nothing")
} else {
    nav.pushViewController(profileVC, animated: true)
}
```

but it never says the two are equal. How do I make an if statement to check if the last view controller pushed is profileVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the type

```
if nav.viewControllers.last is ProfileVC {
   print("Do nothing") 
}
else { 
  nav.pushViewController(profileVC, animated: true) 
}
```

Currently you compare 2 instances of the same type and for sure they are not equal

Comment: When I try that it gives me an error about profileVC saying 'Use of undeclared type 'profileVC''

Comment: Bingo! Solved it. Thank you!!